# Materializecss checkbox nested in collapsible

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, materialize

I need to please help from you to help me with the nested checkboxes inside a collapsible of Materializecss. I have the following code:

**vehicle.component.html**

```
<ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
  <li *ngFor="let items of fleets">
    <div class="collapsible-header"> <i class="material-icons">airport_shuttle</i>
      <input type="checkbox" id="{{items.id}}" />
      <label for="{{items.id}}">{{ items.nameFleet }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="collapsible-body">
      <ul>
        <li *ngFor="let item of items.vehicles">
            <input type="checkbox" id="{{item.id}}" />
            <label for="{{item.id}}">{{item.nameVehicle}}</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**index.js**

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function () {
  if (this.checked) {
    $(this).parents('li').children('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', true);
  }
  $(this).parent().find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',this.checked);
});
```

The problem I have is that when I click on any main checkbox, I do not recognize the dependents.

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Did you give https://github.com/InfomediaLtd/angular2-materialize a try? Because a lot of things should be taken care of when using Angular with raw Materialize and jQuery.

Comment: Yes, angular2-materialize is installed in the project. The problem is that I can not identify the event of the first checkbox for the rest to be checked too

Comment: Usually this is handled already with `materialize` directive. If this isn't so, I'd suggest to try this first. If this is, it's unclear why you're doing this with jQuery.